# form_set_error on taxonomy fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

While `form_set_error('field_firstname', t('message'));` works fine, how can I do the same for one of several taxonomy fields? e.g. `form_set_error('taxonomy[5]', t('message'));` (which doesn't work). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Here it is, for anyone who might have the same problem:

> If the #parents property of your form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'.

So `form_set_error('taxonomy][5', t('message'));` works perfectly.